# Why I'm getting message in the editor console window , Look rotation viewing vector is zero?

Tags: unity, c#

Look rotation viewing vector is zero
UnityEngine.Quaternion:LookRotation (UnityEngine.Vector3)
Waypoints:Update ()

Why I'm getting this message and what should I do with it ? It's not a warning and not some error.

On the Line :

```
var rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(nextWayPoint.position - npcs[i].position);
```

[image: Message in console]

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Waypoints : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<Transform> waypoints = new List<Transform>();
    public List<Transform> npcs = new List<Transform>();
    public float movementSpeed;
    public float rotationSpeed;
    public bool reverse = false;
    public bool go = false;
    public int numberOfWaypoints;
    public int nextWaypointNumber;

    private int waypointIndex = 0;
    private Transform nextWayPoint;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            GameObject go = new GameObject();
            go.transform.position = new Vector3(Random.Range(0, 10), Random.Range(0, 10), Random.Range(0, 10));
            waypoints.Add(go.transform);
        }

        numberOfWaypoints = waypoints.Count;

        if (reverse)
        {
            waypointIndex = waypoints.Count - 1;
        }
        else
        {
            waypointIndex = 0;
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (go)
        {
            if (reverse && waypointIndex == 0)
            {
                waypointIndex = waypoints.Count - 1;
            }

            if (reverse == false && waypointIndex == waypoints.Count)
            {
                waypointIndex = 0;
            }

            nextWayPoint = waypoints[waypointIndex];

            nextWaypointNumber = waypointIndex;

            for (int i = 0; i < npcs.Count; i++)
            {
                npcs[i].position = Vector3.MoveTowards(npcs[i].position,
                    waypoints[waypointIndex].position, Time.deltaTime * movementSpeed);

                var rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(nextWayPoint.position - npcs[i].position);
                transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(npcs[i].rotation, rotation, Time.deltaTime * rotationSpeed);

                float distance = Vector3.Distance(npcs[i].position, waypoints[waypointIndex].position);
                if (distance <= 0f)
                {
                    numberOfWaypoints--;

                    if (reverse)
                    {
                        waypointIndex--;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        waypointIndex++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < waypoints.Count; i++)
        {
            Gizmos.color = Color.green;

            Gizmos.DrawSphere(waypoints[i].position, 0.1f);
        }

        if (nextWayPoint != null && npcs != null)
        {
            Gizmos.color = Color.red;

            for (int i = 0; i < npcs.Count; i++)
            {
                Gizmos.DrawLine(npcs[i].position, nextWayPoint.position);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you think the message could mean? What have you done to solve it? There seems to be mentions about this error elsewhere, are there no pre-existing solutions to dealing with this? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is telling you exactly what's wrong: "Look rotation viewing vector is zero".

When your NPC has exactly reached the next waypoint, then `nextWayPoint.position - npcs[i].position` is a zero vector (0, 0, 0).

When you pass a vector to `Quaternion.LookRotation`, you're asking it to "turn to look in this direction".

When you pass a zero vector, the "direction" you're telling it to look in is "nowhere".

How do you rotate so that you're facing nowhere? You can't. The LookRotation method cannot do anything reasonable in response to this input. So it logs an error, to let you know that you asked it to do something impossible.

You can avoid this error by doing something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < npcs.Count; i++)
{
    npcs[i].position = Vector3.MoveTowards(npcs[i].position,
                waypoints[waypointIndex].position, Time.deltaTime * movementSpeed);

    float distance = Vector3.Distance(npcs[i].position, waypoints[waypointIndex].position);
    if (distance > 0f) {
         // Try to rotate to face the waypoint only if we're not on top of it.
         var rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(nextWayPoint.position - npcs[i].position);
         transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(npcs[i].rotation, rotation, Time.deltaTime * rotationSpeed);
    } else {
         numberOfWaypoints--;

         if (reverse)
         {
             waypointIndex--;
         }
         else
         {
             waypointIndex++;
         }
     }
 }
```